# Sort posts by most recently modified

Tags: loop, get-posts, sort

Is there a way to list posts in the order in which they were modified?

For example;

A user posts 5 posts (#1 being the oldest and #5 being the newest), by default they would be listed with #5 being at the top, but say the user edited post #3 at a later date, is it possible to then list post #3 above #5 without manually changing the page attributes?

This is a secondary query by the way, using get_posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) you can set the `orderby` to `modified` and then the order to `DESC` and you'll be good to go.  If it's not a custom query, you can just use the `set()` method on the default `$wp_query` global to do the same.  Since `get_posts()` is just a wrapper for `WP_Query`, you can set the `orderby` parameter there if everything else is working and not change anything else.